# Android: Do an action when touching switch

Tags: android

How can I do something when a switch widget has been touched?

Basically, I need to do an action when the switch has been turned off and different action when it has been turned on.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/develop/index.html

Comment: @avi12 Please get used to check the documentation before posting a question and accept answers if they solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

Read the documentation, 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html

it's just a listener, like the `onClick`

```
mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangedListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
       if(isChecked) doSomething();
       else doSomethingElse();
    }
});
```